# How can you pipe email to c# ASP.net web site in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, email

I am looking for my c# web site hosted in azure as a Web Site not VM to receive emails I can process.

I can see how to do this with iis but not azure.

Comment: Tool/software/service recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. Plus this isn't a programming question.

Comment: I am looking for a code solution how to pipe emails not a 3rd party

Comment: I have updated the answer. I feel looking at the type of questions FAQ it falls in to a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: You didn't show any code, so now the question is a "write my code for me" question. This is still off-topic. And, to me, really broad and opinion-soliciting as well.

Comment: I have a specific problem that will have a specific solution. How would  improve the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twillio has an inbound email webhook, that when a message is received it will forward it to an http endpoint.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook

Answer (score 0):

@John, I am assuming you are looking for recommendations.

Currently, in Azure there are no built-in options to send emails. One should be using SMTP relay service to achieve this.

See this links:
http://sendgrid.com/azure.html
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure/